# If $F(x)=\int_a^x f(t)\,dt$, then there exists an $L\geq 0$ st $|F(x)-F(y)| \leq L|x-y|$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

The only conditions are that $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$.

Unsure on how to proceed on this question. By the FTC, we know that $F$ is continuous. Beyond that, I'm pretty lost. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: What are the conditions on $f$ and $x$?

Comment: @DanielFischer Only that $f$ is Riemann Integrable on the closed interval $[a,b]$.

Comment: For example, if $f$ is bounded, then surely $\max{f}$ is a suitable choice of the Lipschitz constant.

Comment: Okay. Part of the definition of a Riemann integrable function is that it is bounded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The notion you're interested in is called Lipschitz continuity.

As I said in my comment, if $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ is bounded, then
$$
|F(x)-F(y)|=|\int_y^xf(t)dt|\leq\max_{x\in[a, b]}|f(x)||x-y|.
$$
Conversely, the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity) on Lipschitz continuous functions tells us that $F$ is Lipschitz continuous iff its first derivative ($f$ in your case) is bounded. If that's not the case, Lipschitz continuity will not hold.

**EDIT** As pointed out in the comments, since Riemann integrability implies boundedness, this value of Lipschitz constant is always valid in your case.

Comment: A bit of caution here:  "iff" meaning "if and only if" is not quite correct.  A Lipschitz function need not be differentiable.  But it would be true that,  if there is a set of points where the derivative exists and is unbounded, then the function cannot be Lipschitz.

Comment: You're right and possibly I should have been more rigorous, but since the OP was interested in the particular case of an integral with a variable upper limit (which is differentiable) I allowed some slackness in my explanation.